# Can you complete the "BODY TRIPLE" 2017 International Battle Pass quest with self debuffs?

Tags: dota-2

from http://dota2.gamepedia.com/The_International_2017_Battle_Pass#Path_of_the_Wave_Breaker

it reads:-

Purge 5 / 10 / 15 debuffs using Manta Style

can you use something like glimmer cape, and then manta to complete this quest without relying on something else doing something to you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.**

These "self-effects" are generally good and are called *buffs*, not *debuffs*. Buff and debuff icons are shown above the character health bar. Buffs (friendly effects) are shown in green, and debuffs (enemy effects) in red. As described [on the wiki](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Dispel):

> Dispels remove status effects based on whether the casting unit is an ally or an enemy, and whether the status effect is positive or negative. Applying a dispel on an allied unit only removes negative effects (also known as debuffs). Positive effects (known as buffs) are never removed.

There *may* be some exceptions I'm not aware of.

What you **can do** is find a group of [prowler ancient creeps](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Prowler_Camp). The large prowler shaman reliably casts two debuffs (a root and negative armor) which can both be dispelled with Manta Style. The root doesn't even cost mana, so a single camp will do if you don't kill it. I did this yesterday to achieve the first star near the end of a game.

This should also work with the [vhoul's poison](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Vhoul_Assassin_Camp) and the [ghost's slow](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Ghost_Camp). The [hellbear's thunder clap](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Hellbear_Camp) slow and [Roshan's slam](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Roshan#Slam) slow can be dispelled but both of those need 3 enemy units nearby to cast. The [small satyr's purge](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Satyr_Camp) slow, the [ogre frostmages's frost armor](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Ogre_Camp) slow, the [troll summoner's net](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Troll_Camp) root and the [thunderhide's slam](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Thunderhide_Camp) slow can be dispelled, but neutral camps will never cast these spells.

Comment: I think there are currently 4 exceptions: Etheral (the item), storm spirit self-slow during grip, oracles fate edict and bloodseekers rage. They are all dispellable, but I'm not sure if they count for the actual achievement.

Comment: @Ordous Interesting, I didn't realise that Electric Vortex and Fate's Edict are always as debuffs. I wonder if it would work. The wiki lists e-blade and Bloodrage as being a buff for allied casting; are you sure they can be dispelled from allies?

Comment: That's been changed a bit over the years, you might be right. I might have grabbed it off an old aggregate site (can't verify at work, sorry). E-blade is tricky, since you get the effect independent of who you cast it on, and it has a separate self-cast. I'll have a look in the evening.

Comment: Just tested it - and you are right about E-blade and Bloodrage - they are buffs if self-cast. Electric Vortex slow and Fate's Edict are both debuffs and are dispellable via Manta. Not sure they count towards the achievement, as I do not have this years' battlepass, but I don't see a reason they wouldn't.

Comment: @Ordous Yeah, I'd expect it to work then. Good research!